# Create matrix with np (python)

Tags: python, numpy

MATLAB refugee here with a simple numpy question:

I want to copy the dimensions of a matrix, and in this new matrix add the variable i in one column and the rest with zeroes.

Pretty straightforward, but really appreciate the help!

Happy monday

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: If you can do it in MATLAB, numpy does it almost the same way. Please provide a MATLAB example.

Answer (score 1):

Numpy lets you initialize a zero-filled array, similiar to matlab.
You can copy the dimensions of another array via its shape attribute:

```py
import numpy as np

dimensions = (2,3)  # rows, columns
matrix_a = np.random.randn(*dimensions)  # initial matrix filled with random numbers

matrix_b = np.zeros(matrix_a.shape)  # create zero-matrix with dimensions copied from matrix a
i_col = 1  # target column. mind zero indexing, i.e. 1 = 2nd column
filler = 42
matrix_b[:, i_col] = filler  # fill target column with filler
```

Answer (score 0):

You create a matrix filled with zeros using [np.zeros](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html) with the corresponding dimensions, then you choose the targeted column to fill it with ones

Code:

```
import numpy as np
n,m=int(input()),int(input())
dim = (n,m)
arr=np.zeros(dim)
col = 1  
arr[:, col] = 1
print(arr)
```

Input:

```
2
3
```

Output:

```
[[0. 1. 0.]
[0. 1. 0.]]
```